# Getting distinct / unique objects with NSFetchRequest / Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I understand how to get unique data from Core Data using `NSFetchRequest` with `setReturnsDistinctResults:YES`.  However, I cannot figure out how to do this when I define uniqueness as something more than 1 data value.

For instance, if I have an object I'm loading through Core Data defined like this:

```
People {
  String First,
  String Last
}
```

It seems easy to me to define uniqueness on First *OR* Last, but not on BOTH of them.

Furthermore, the results need to come back as instances of this People object so that I can then manipulate them.  I'm not interested in just knowing if there is a unique name "John Doe" I need back the full object.  Imagine the object People above having many more fields (address, phone numbers, etc) but for our purpose we define uniqueness as the AND of these fields.

Example:

```
John, Doe, 123 Street
Jane, Doe, 123 Street
John, Doe, 456 Street
```

What I want is objects for Jane Doe and an object for John Doe.  Given I haven't defined how to pick between these two, I accept that it could be either.

So I want something back like:

```
Array of Peoples { JohnDoeObject, JaneDoeObject }
```

Can someone help explain how to do this?

Thanks!